# Remove empty columns in an excel file using phpexcel library

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel library to read an excel file.It works perfeclty on 99%. But sometimes it reads empty columns also.My code is

```
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file');
}   

$worksheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();) {
$worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
```

sometimes the $highestcolumn returns 'WVL' even if the data in excel column up to 'C' why?.
Also i want to check all the rows under a particular column is empty or not,Is there any easy method to do it instead of iterating  all rows using for loop.

Comment: hi do you wont get highest column of sheet or highest column with data ?

Comment: i want highest column with data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getHighestRow()` and `getHighestColumn()` methods work on the basis of testing for ***anything*** related to a cell, even if that's a style setting or a named range or print settings or a column/row setting such as width/height or hidden.

That's why the `getHighestDataRow()` and `getHighestDataColumn()` methods exist. These two methods look at the actual data in cells.

**Note:** Just because a cell looks empty when you view it in MS Excel, doesn't mean that it actually is empty. NULL is a valid cell value, as is a space character, neither of which is visible.

---

In answer to your second question: you can pass an optional argument to the `getHighestRow()`, `getHighestColumn()` and to the `getHighestDataRow()` and `getHighestDataColumn()`, so a row number passed to `getHighestColumn()` or `getHighestDataColumn()` will return the highest column in the specified row; and a column letter passed to `getHighestRow()` or `getHighestDataRow()` will return the highest row in that column.

e.g.

```
$highestColumnInRow5 = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(5);
```

or

```
$highestDataRowInColumnAA = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow('AA');
```

Comment: is there any way to take all the rows under a particular column into an array ?

Comment: Using the worksheets rangeToArray() method, you can specify a range, e.g. `$column = 'C'; $data = $worksheet->rangeToArray($column.'1:'.$column.$worksheet->getHighestDataRow($column));`